# RecyclerView loads list of images with endless scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm making an app that shows some beautiful girls in `RecyclerView` with load more when scroll to bottom. And i am stuck with few issues, you can see it in [videos link here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6TYFEPmFRUCLTd2elBCaVU0aEE/view?usp=sharing)

Or:

I. When add more items, it shows only one column not all 3 columns as defined.

II. When scroll up, all child views is moving very fast and after that, `RecyclerView` brings me to the top and skip all items among. Sample: current item is 100 and scroll up, a few milliseconds you stand on top of list.

My project has:

1. `build.grade: compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'`: I don't want to update `RecyclerView` to 24 because of JDK version.
2. **MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity:**

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private RelativeLayout rootView;
   private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
   private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
   private ImagesAdapter mAdapter;
   private Handler mHandler;

   private int currentOffset;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       currentOffset = 0;
       loading = true;
       mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
       initRetrofit();
       initWidget();

       fetchingData(true);
   }

   private void initRetrofit() {
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
       OkHttpClient.Builder builderHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
       //builderHttpClient.interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());
       OkHttpClient client = builderHttpClient.build();

       NetworkManager.init(new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIConfig.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).client(client).build());
   }

   private void initWidget() {
       mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
       mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
       mAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(this, new ArrayList<PhotoItemModel>());

       mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
       mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(15));
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

       mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
           @Override
           public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
               if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
               {
                   visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                   totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

                   int[] items = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(null);
                   if (items.length > 0) {
                       pastVisibleItems = items[0];
                   }

                   if (loading) {
                       if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                           loading = false;
                           fetchingData();
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       });
   }

   private void fetchingData() {
       currentOffset = mAdapter.getItemCount();
       mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               NetworkManager.getPhotoByOffset(currentOffset, new Callback<GetPhotoResponse>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(Call<GetPhotoResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<GetPhotoResponse> response) {
                       if (null != response && null != response.body()) {
                           ResponseModel responseModel = response.body().getResponseModel();
                           List<PostItemModel> postItemModels = responseModel.getPostItemModels();
                           List<PhotoItemModel> photoItemModels = new ArrayList<>();
                           for (PostItemModel postItemModel : postItemModels) {
                               photoItemModels.addAll(postItemModel.getPhotos());
                           }
                           mAdapter.insertMoreItems(photoItemModels);
                           loading = true;
                       } else {
                           loading = true;
                           fetchingData();
                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(Call<GetPhotoResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                       t.printStackTrace();
                       loading = true;
                       fetchingData();
                   }
               });
           }
       }, 5000);
   }
   }
   ```
3. **Adapter:**

   ```
   public class ImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VHImage> {
   private MainActivity mainActivity;
   private List<PhotoItemModel> photoItemModels;

   public ImagesAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<PhotoItemModel> photoItemModels) {
       this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
       this.photoItemModels = photoItemModels;
   }

   public List<PhotoItemModel> getPhotoItemModels() {
       return photoItemModels;
   }

   @Override
   public VHImage onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false);
       return new VHImage(mainActivity, view);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(VHImage holder, int position) {
       holder.bindData(photoItemModels.get(position));
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return photoItemModels.size();
   }

   public void insertMoreItems(List<PhotoItemModel> morePhotoItemModels) {
       int oldSize = photoItemModels.size();
       photoItemModels.addAll(morePhotoItemModels);
       notifyItemRangeInserted(oldSize, morePhotoItemModels.size());
   }
   }
   ```
4. **ViewHolder**

   ```
   public class VHImage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
   private MainActivity mainActivity;
   private ImageView ivImage;
   private View div1, div2;
   private PhotoItemModel photoItemModel;

   public VHImage(MainActivity mainActivity, View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
       ivImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
       div1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.v_div_1);
       div2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.v_div_2);
       ivImage.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   public void bindData(PhotoItemModel photoItemModel) {
       this.photoItemModel = photoItemModel;
       Glide.with(mainActivity.getApplicationContext())
               .load(photoItemModel.getAltSizesList().get(2).getUrl())
               .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
               .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                       div1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       div2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       return false;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                       div1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       div2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       return false;
                   }
               })
               .into(ivImage);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       mainActivity.onImageClick(view, ((ImageView) view).getDrawable(), photoItemModel);
   }
   }
   ```
5. **activity layout**

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rv_main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="0.5dp"
       android:visibility="invisible" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_full_screen"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:visibility="invisible" />


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_splash1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:visibility="gone" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_splash2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:visibility="gone" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/iv_splash1"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:indeterminate="true"
       android:max="1000"
       android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable" />
   ```
6. **item layout**

   ```
   <View
       android:id="@+id/v_div_1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:background="#000000"
       android:visibility="invisible" />

   <View
       android:id="@+id/v_div_2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
       android:background="#000000"
       android:visibility="invisible" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/iv_image"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="0.5dp"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
   ```

Comment: I think retrofit is not able to load all the images so fast. Check if that is the case, if yes then create a listener which detects if all the images are loaded then enables scroll down. Till then show a progress dialog

Comment: I use Glide for loading images and i found something so strange.
That is ImageView in **6.item layout**. If i let it's **height = wrap_content** and **adjustViewBounds="true"** then i get problem but if i change **height = xxdp**, it's resolved. But i don't wanna set it with specific height.
Still finding another solution...

Answer (score 0):

Before download an image, You cannot find its size unless you send your image size from webservice and setting your `ImageView` height before you show it.

For example your webservice response could be something like that:

```
{
    "ImageLink" = "http://www.example.com/example.jpg"
    "ImageWidth" = 1024
    "ImageHeight" = 768
}
```

Then set your `ImageView` size like this:

```
imageview.getLayoutParams().height = imageview.getWidth() * (ImageHeight/ImageWidth);
```

For better performance, set `ImageView` layout size before you add it to `RecyclerView`.